# Are there more instructions for LEGO Architecture Studio?

Tags: sets, instructions, architecture

I have a LEGO Architecture Studio set of 1210 pieces. The set have a book about architecture and techniques but it have no instructions for, e.g. build a pyramid, building or others. So I want to know if exists instructions for this, and where could I find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so.  I've found a few places that show nothing but the original book for it in terms of official LEGO content:

- http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/21050/Architectuer_Studio
- https://www.repubrick.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=451&virtuemart_category_id=38&lang=en
- https://www.reddit.com/r/architecture/comments/1k108y/the_lego_architecture_studio_manual_via_legos/

## Tom Alphin's book

While it isn't entirely instructions it does include lots of instructions: [Tom Alphin's book *The Lego Architect*](http://a.co/3w1gV9r).  It has been a while since I flipped through it so I just gave it another skim.  I'd say that a third to a half of the pages are dedicated to detailed instructions.  The rest of it is lovely inspiration so it isn't like filler.

[image: book cover]

## Brick Architect blog

Tom Alphin also has created a blog that has lots of LEGO architecture designs in it: http://brickarchitect.com/ but I didn't see any instructions there.  It is still probably worth checking out for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, I´m out of ideas, I've been building many things with this LEGO set, and I wanted to find instructions to try other buildings.